# WPF Toolbar buttons don't seem to respond

Tags: wpf, button, toolbar

I have the following code:

```
    <ToolBarTray Margin="0,21,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ToolBar Height="38">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=btnStyle}" Command="Cut" IsEnabled="True">
                <Image Source="images/teren.png" ToolTip="Test" />
            </Button>
        </Toolbar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

The style in question only changes the height and width at the moment. Every element is drawn accordingly, but the button seems to be non functional in the sense that for all purposes it looks like an image rather than anything else. The tooltip won't display, it has no hover animation and it can't really be pressed.

I'm new to WPF so I'm guessing I missed something big.

The problem isn't in the image. If I remove that line, it still doesn't act like a button at all.

Comment: check [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2012/09/06/a-wpf-image-button.aspx) to create imagebutton usercontrol to accept the image with effects that button should have..

Answer (score 1):

The reason the button is greyed out is because you have told it to use the built-in cut command. This means that the `Button` will be automatically disabled when there is nothing to cut and enabled when something that can be cut is selected (such as text).

To verify this you can do two things; either remove the cut command and see that the button is now enabled:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ToolBarTray Margin="0,21,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ToolBar Height="38">
                <Button  IsEnabled="True">
                    Click
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Or add a rich text box control and see that the button is enabled when you select some text:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToolBarTray Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ToolBar Height="38" >
                <Button  IsEnabled="True" Command="Cut">
                    Click
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]